# Paste selection of variable range from one workbook to another workbook beginning in a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from cells in column "A" through column "K" in a closed worksheet to an open worksheet, beginning in cell "A4", while keeping the source formatting. Workbook A is the one I am trying to copy from and Workbook is the one I am trying to paste into.

```
Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks.Open Filename:="path to Workbook A", ReadOnly:=True
Windows("Workbook A").Activate
Range("A3" & ":K" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Workbook B").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=PasteAllUsingSourceTheme
```

The error that I am receiving is "Select method of Range class failed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this. This doesn't use the `select` statement but still copies the range just the same as it declares explicitly instead of using `select` statements (which should be avoided as much as possible)

```
Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks.Open Filename:="path to Workbook A", ReadOnly:=True
Workbooks("Workbook A").Range("A3" & ":K" & LastRow).Copy
Workbooks("Workbook B").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
```

---

**Update after further comments:**

Can you try this:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("path to Workbook A", ReadOnly:=True)
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook B")

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Relevant Worksheet in A")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Relevant Worksheet in B")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("A3" & ":K" & LastRow)

rng.Copy

With ws2
    .Cells(Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
End With
```

Comment: That took care of the "Select method of Range class failed" error but another problem has surfaced; the cells being copied are in Workbook B instead of Workbook A, even though I used  Windows("Workbook A").Activate

Comment: @rstuart931 I've updated and combined the `.Activate` line with the `.Copy` This again will declare the range explicitly to the workbook. You might want to do something similar with the `LastRow` statement as you are currently counting the number of rows in what I assume is 'Workbook B' then using that value to declare the range in 'Workbook A'

Comment: you were right about the LastRow, I moved it  and did a watch to see that it is now reading the right Workbook. I declaring the range explicitly, as you suggested; and I receive the following error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I appreciate the time you are taking with this.

Comment: Sorry, had trouble with the comments. I am receiving the following error "Object doesn't support this property or method" associate with the line     Workbooks("Workbook A").Range("A3" & ":K" & LastRow).Copy

Comment: what is `LastRow` evaluating to?

Comment: LastRow is supposed to find the last row with data in it, which it is doing. The restructured code you have written works great except that it is copying it to ws2 beginning in "D3" instead of "A4". I have changed part of the with statement to '.Row, 1)' Is now copying into Column A but it is not starting in cell A4. I should have stated that I want to copy over existing data in ws2

Comment: I included 'Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A4")' and changed the with statement to 'rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme'. Works great now, Thank you for all your help. You gave me a valuable lesson in the use of variables.

Comment: Glad it's now sorted